# Ionic ng-repeat not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova

It seemed to work on phonegap correctly, however crashed a few times while making changes. However while installing ionic, covoda correctly via npm terminal this ng-repeat doesn't seem to work.

My controller:

```js
.controller('feedCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$ionicHistory,$state,$http) {

    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        


        $http.jsonp('https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id='+$scope.session_id).then(function(response){
           $scope.feeds = response.data;
        });



    }
    
})
```

My HTML

```html
<ion-view title="Feed" id="page6">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left" class="has-header">
    <button class="button button-icon icon No Icon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    

<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds">

    <ion-list id="search-list5">
      <ion-item class="item-avatar" id="search-list-item12">
        <img ng-src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.profile_image}}">
        <h2>{{feed.firstname}} {{feed.lastname}}</h2>
        <p>{{feed.location}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239); text-align: center;">
      <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" ng-src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{feed.media_file_format}}/{{feed.media_post_id}}{{feed.media_author_id}}.{{feed.media_file_format}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="item item-body" id="search-list-item-container3">
      <div id="search-markdown6" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
        <p style="margin-top:0px;color:#000000;">{{feed.mediatxt}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: It's not completely clear where it isn't working. If you try it to run in a desktop browser, probably you get some CORS errors.
Additionally, I would recommend you improving your API-s backend, because it doesn't seems to be protected against SQL injection: https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id=media.userID

Comment: Well, in the network requests on the console log on Chrome, its showing the ID is being passed through, and the php page is generating a json array.

Comment: Even when you have CORS errors the Network tab will show you the request. You can see the exception in the Console. I suggest you, to implement the error handling branch of your request and you will see the problem there too.

Comment: you may have an .catch() to see if there is any error in sending request .then().catch(function(err){ console.log(err); });